# R Shiny server on Ubuntu disconnects with server after upload file more than maximum upload size(5MB)

Tags: r, ubuntu, server, shiny

I have installed shiny server in Ubuntu 16.04.2 which I use as my computer. I can connect to server and see my application from any computer connected from network when i enter the host-name on address line. The problem is; when try to upload a data file (CSV) that more than 5MB, it accepts the file and upload it. But after 1 or 2 seconds (I guess when it starts the reading function in server.R)  it disconnects with server.

This is the code which allow to upload file more then 5MB. I wrote this code into global.R file.

```
 if(Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') != "") {
 options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10000*1024^2)
 }
```

I have also tried :

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10000*1024^2)
```

And here my reading function for data file in server.R

```
  Dataset <- reactive({
  if (is.null(input$data1)) {
  # User has not uploaded a file yet
  return(data.frame())
  }
  inFile <- input$data1
  Dataset <- as.data.frame(do.call( "read.csv", args = 
  list(inFile$datapath,
                                          header = input$header,
                                          sep    =  input$sep,
                                           quote =  input$quote
  )))

  })
```

Thank you

Comment: can you try with this code http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

Comment: I have tried it. If I don't add the  `shiny.maxRequestSize`  function into server.R, I can't even upload file more than 5MB. After I added that function, it doesn't disconnect with server but gives error. Like  `An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification`